# cast numerics to double efficiently

Tags: java

I have a bunch of numeric values. They can be `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float` or `Double` (and are the output of an external library (snakeYaml) which returns these as type `Object`)

I'd like to convert these Objects (which are guaranteed to be `Numbers`) to `Double` values in my program. (Storage space is not an issue).

The Java compiler obviously throws a `ClassCastException` when attempting to cast from an object which is actually an `Short`/`Integer`/`Long`/`Float` to a `Double`.

Any hints as to the most efficient method to adopt would be gratefully acknowledged.

Comment: If you are really worried about efficiency, I would suggest you not use Objects when you could be using primitives. However, I doubt efficiency is really your problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***They can be Short, Integer, Long, Float or Double***

These classes are all subclasses of the [`Number`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class, which means that you can always use the [`Number.doubleValue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue%28%29) method.

**Example:**

```
Number[] nums = { new Double(1.2), new Integer(5), new Float(3.0) };

double num1 = nums[0].doubleValue();
double num2 = nums[1].doubleValue();
double num3 = nums[2].doubleValue();
```

or, if you really want `Double` values, you can rely on autoboxing and simply do:

```
Double num1 = nums[0].doubleValue();
Double num2 = nums[1].doubleValue();
Double num3 = nums[2].doubleValue();
```

Comment: +1: Also I'd think just storing them as doubles anyhow and let autoboxing handle the boxing is the better approach in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Number.doubleValue()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#doubleValue%28%29) method to achieve that. With autoboxing you can assing its return value directly do `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to cast to `Double` instead of `double`. But that only works for the Objects that are really Doubles and not Integer or Long or Float etc.

To get around that, cast to `Number` and use `doubleValue()`

```
Object o = 10;
double i = ((Number)o).doubleValue();
```

ps. I'm unfamiliar with snakeYaml, but the api you describe is either designed completely wrong, or you are using it wrong. It makes no sense to return numbers as Objects. Would be interesting to see some example code of how you use it.